# Does Google use any “Language” flags / tags set within a PDF file when determining its language?

Tags: seo, google, multilingual, accessibility, pdf

When determining the language of a *HTML* page, I understand that Google looks at any language declarations that the page owner has set, and then also applies its own language detection algorithms.

But does Google similarly look at language meta data set in PDF files when determining a PDF file's language?  (Authors of PDF files can set [document-wide properties](http://www.commonlook.com/Setting-Language-Attributes) describing the language (or languages) contained within it.)

Or does Google rely exclusively on language detection algorithms and disregard the language flag set within the PDF file?

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's my understanding that we at Google don't use any of the language meta-information within PDF files. You can, however, use the [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) information via HTTP header or Sitemaps file for non-HTML content too.